# Calculating the value of upper limit.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{M}\frac{b^a}{\Gamma(a)}x^{a-1}\exp[-bx]=0.5$$

What will be the value of the upper limit $M$?

I know that if the limit were $(0,\infty)$, then the integral would be $1$, as the integrand is so called [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Characterization_using_shape_.CE.B1_and_rate_.CE.B2).

Comment: By a change of variables, the parameter $b$ can disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $a\gt 0$ and $b\gt 0$, $$\int_0^M x^{a-1}e^{-bx}dx=b^{-a} (\Gamma (a)-\Gamma (a,b M))$$ where appears the incomplete gamma function. Using this, $$\int_{0}^{M}\frac{b^a}{\Gamma(a)}x^{a-1}e^{-bx} dx=\frac{\Gamma (a)-\Gamma (a,b M)}{\Gamma (a)}=1-\frac{\Gamma (a,b M)}{\Gamma (a)}$$ In other words, you want to solve for $M$$$\frac{\Gamma (a,b M)}{\Gamma (a)}=\frac 12$$ the solution of which being non explicit (have a look [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseGammaRegularized3/introductions/Gammas/05/)). Matlab has a built in function for it (have a look [here](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gammaincinv.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)).

**Edit**

Looking [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.7#E3), you will find the Taylor expansion $$\Gamma(a,z)
= \Gamma(a)-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}z^{a+k}}{k!(a+k)}
=\Gamma(a)\left(1-z^ae^{-z}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{\Gamma(a+k+1)}\right)$$ which could be of interest to you.

Assuming that we could limit the expansion to its first term, this would lead to $$\frac{e^{-b M} (b M)^a}{\Gamma (a+1)}=\frac{1}{2}$$the solution of which being given using Lambert function $$ M=-\frac a b\, W\left(-\frac{ \Gamma (a+1)^{\frac{1}{a}}}{a\,2^{1/a}}\right)$$ If this is not sufficient, only numerical method could be used (using $bM$ as a variable).

Considering that we need to find the zero of $$f(x)=\Gamma (a,x)-\frac{1}{2}\Gamma (a)$$ using as a "reasonable" guess $x_0=a$ , Newton iterates would be $$x_{n+1}=x_n+e^{x_n} {x_n}^{1-a} \left(\Gamma (a,x_n)-\frac{\Gamma (a)}{2}\right)$$

Playing with integer values of $a$ $(1\leq a \leq 50)$, what I found using  regression is $$x= a-0.331329\approx a-\frac 13$$ which gives as a (good) approximation $$M\approx\frac{3a-1} {3b}$$

Let us try using $a=100$ : the above approximation gives $bM=\frac{299}{3}\approx 99.66667$ while the "exact" solution would be $bM\approx 99.66687$

Assuming that the solution could be approximated by $x=a+k$, the numerical minimization of $$\Phi(k)=\int_{1}^{50} \left(\Gamma (a,a+k)-\frac{\Gamma (a)}{2}-(a+k) \right)^2\,da$$ lead to $k\approx -0.332934$ still closer to $-\frac 13$ than the number obtained from linear regression based on the $50$ integer values.

Integrating from $0$ to $1000$, the solution is almost exactly $k=-\frac 13$.